# Is the clause after 'and' in the sentence "His voice was serious and his manner solemn." valid?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Is the sentence "His voice was serious and his manner solemn." grammatically correct? I've seen 'be' dropped in some sentences like this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proper example of a "stripping ellipsis." See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Stripping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29#Stripping)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct. The verb "was" is implicitly carried over to the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! the verb "was" is implicit in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as others have noted, the verb is implied in the second sentence.
The same structure is sometimes achieved using a semicolon:

> His voice was serious; his manner, solemn.

This works for other verbs than *to be* as well:

> They seemed to be a different species, and he looked at them and they at him with distrust and hostility.  (Fyodor Dostoyevsky, *Crime and Punishment*)